# Python - incorrect colors when using opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to randomly generate colored pixels in a white frame using opencv but the pixels are generated with the wrong color. Is there any way to fix this problem?
this is my code:

```
import random
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("anhnen.png")
i=1
while i <= 200:
   i = i+1
   x = random.randint(0,479)
   y = random.randint(0,479)    
   img[x][y] = [255,0,0]


cv2.imwrite('anh2.png', img)
```

Here is the picture after running the code
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqJvB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV uses a BGR color format by default. Change your code to `[0, 0, 255]`

Comment: it was working properly. Thank you very much.